# Get EE to respect SSI include

Tags: templates

We have a legacy system slowly getting migrated to full EE. We call an SSI include from within one of the files used by both systems.

The problem is, EE doesn't respect the SSI include and just shows a blank area where our content should be.

So, I'm looking at either:

1. Duplicating the include file and changing the SSI include to an EE include, or
2. Creating a script to bake the include content into our file before it gets called by either system.

The first just duplicates any work we have to do to our menu, the second seems like overkill.

I'm wondering if anyone else has any suggestions? I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would think a line or two of PHP in your EE template (make sure to turn on PHP within) will allow you to include the file.

Comment: I can't turn PHP on in EE. Other suggestions?